# Different behaviour of Map and Inner in replace rules

Tags: evaluation, replacement, map, inner

Why does

```
x[{1, 2}] /. {x[l_] -> Map[func, l]}
```

> `{1, 2}`

not behave as expected, while for example

```
x[{1, 2}] /. {x[l_] -> Inner[func, l, l]}
```

> `func[1, 1] + func[2, 2]`

gives the expected result?

I know that I can fix the first example by using `:>` instead of `->`, but I don't understand why.

Is there another way to make the example with `Map` work as in the case of `Inner`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your first case,

```
Map[func,l]
```

will evaluate to verbatim `l` while building up the replacement rules. When the replacement is then done, the replacement rule used is `x[l_] -> l`.

My guess why `Map[func, l]` evaluates the way it does is that Map works by "inserting" `func` into it's second argument at the default mapping level, 1. As there is no such level because `l` is an atomic symbol, the result is just `l`.

In the second case

```
Inner[func, l, l]
```

`Inner` does not evaluate to something different, so it survives until the `l` is replaced with the value from the left side of the rule.

Using `:>` is really the right way to go when there are patterns on the left hand side.

Comment: Ok, but why does Map[func,l] evaluate to l in this case?

Comment: @Severin see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Malte Lenz is correct; there are no level one expressions in `l` therefore the `Map` operation appears inert.  (The default *levelspec* of `Map` is `{1}`.)  Observe that if a *levelspec* of `{0}` is used the `func` is applied:

```
Map[func, l, {0}]
```

> ```
> func[l]
> ```

If you are asking why conceptually `Map` works this way I can only say that in my experience the existing behavior has been convenient and powerful many times.  If for whatever reason you want a `Map` analogue that does not evaluate until the operation is non-inert I propose:

```
delayMap[f_, expr_, lev_: {1}, opt : OptionsPattern[Map]] /;
  {} =!= Position[expr, _, lev, 1, Heads -> OptionValue[Map, {opt}, Heads]] := 
     Map[f, expr, lev, opt]
```

Now:

```
test = delayMap2[func, l]
```

> ```
> delayMap[func, l]
> ```

```
l = {1, 2, 3};

test
```

> ```
> {func[1], func[2], func[3]}
> ```

The somewhat baroque definition is primarily to handle the [`Heads`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Heads.html) option of `Map`.